# Inline form fields: search box and button in jQuery-Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile-webkit

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Please view the JSFiddle of this with web-kit browser (Chrome or Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/KqEqN/

This is happening when you narrow the screen but there's still visibly enough space for the button.
I've looked into CSS trying to find some sort of padding to the right of the button but couldn't. Also where the hell that horizontal line comes from?

Comment: also for the added line, remove this attribute: data-role="fieldcontain" from the div and the line(s) will go away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jQuery Mobile, so I might be doing this wrong. My guess is that you must add extra classes instead of overriding jQuery Mobile's theme.

The fix involves:

```
.ui-input-search {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/NqFhQ/

Comment: The `display` directive is enough; the border goes if you remove the `data-role` attribute, as @Phill Pafford says.

Comment: Thanks Ben, removed the css declaration for the line.